# Convert any format of phone number to (111) 111-1111 using python

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, data-cleaning, python-3.x

I have a phone number column in my dataset which has numbers in different formats. Here are some examples:

```
1000101000
111-101-1000
(212)-212-2122
444.456.7890
123 456 7890
+12124567890
```

How do I format all of the above different formats to `(111) 111-1111` format?

Comment: Do you want to keep country codes or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#txt is your phone number that you get from your dataset
filterTxt = list(filter(str.isdigit, txt))
formatTxt=''
for index,number in enumerate(filterTxt) :
 if index==0:
   formatTxt+='('+number
 elif index==2:
   formatTxt+=number+') '
 elif index==5:
   formatTxt+=number+'-'
 else:
   formatTxt+=number
```

Ok let me explain my code. First of all we want to filter only the number the easiest way is to use `list(filter(str.isdigit, txt))`. Filter will read all the string and compare it with `str.isdigit` which is to detect whether the string is digit or not and because we got the number already I then we just format it using `for` since we got the list of number already.